# ctags doesn't search recursively

Tags: python, linux, vim, ctags

I have a folder that contains multiple another folders and python files, I want ctags to search recursively in the current folder, I tried the following command:

```
ctags . -R
```

The result `tags` file is as follows:

```
!_TAG_FILE_FORMAT       2       /extended format; --format=1 will not append ;" to lines/
!_TAG_FILE_SORTED       1       /0=unsorted, 1=sorted, 2=foldcase/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_AUTHOR    Darren Hiebert  /dhiebert@users.sourceforge.net/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_NAME      Exuberant Ctags //
!_TAG_PROGRAM_URL       http://ctags.sourceforge.net    /official site/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_VERSION   5.9~svn20110310 //
```

It seemed that ctags found nothing here, why? I can make it work by running

```
find . -name "*.py" -exec ctags {} +
```

But I just want to know if I'm using ctags in the wrong way.

Comment: Try `ctags -R .` and I don't think the `.` is necessary.

Comment: @KeithThompson It worked, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The synopsis of ctags is the following:

```
ctags [options] [file(s)]
```

This means that you need to provide the options **before** the files. In your specific example, this is what you wanted:

```
ctags -R .
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as @KeithThompson said, using `ctags -R` is enough to generate correct `tags`